# How to make filter that can find users by location of each other in miles or kilometers?

Tags: location

On  a lot of dating sites like this one:

http://www.pof.com/basicsearch.aspx

users can search each other by proximity, can this be done with Drupal? Like searching for users within X kilometers of my IP?

Answer (score 0):

[IP Geolocation Views and Maps](http://drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) looks like what you are looking for. It can obtain user's location, and it integrates with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) using [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) as it's connector.

Comment: Thanks, but can I do this without Views PHP, I can't code..

Comment: IP Geolocation Views and Maps itself uses Views PHP for some of it's tasks. And if you can't code, you probably should hire at least one person who can anyway if you plan to build complex sites like dating ones.